# JavaScript onChange for Date is not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, prototypejs

I have the below snippet of my code.

```
<tr>
            <td>
                <%= "MHC Date" %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= text_field :candidate_mhc_detail, :mhc_date, :class => 'txtinputs', :id => "mhc_date", :value => showdate(Date.today), :style => ["width:80px;"], :onChange => "return validate_date();" %>
                <a id="_mhc_date_link" onclick="DatePicker.toggleDatePicker('mhc_date')" class="demo_link"><img src="/images/calendar.png" width="20" height="20" /></a>
                <div id="_mhc_date_calendar" class="date_picker" style="display:none">
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

The value of text field i.e, MHC Date is default set to `Date.today` and if that value is changed, I need to perform a javascript alert showing that "MHC Date should be the today's Date", but I'm having trouble performing this with `onChange`

**My JavaScript:**

```
function validate_date(){
        if ($F('mhc_date') != Date.today)
        {
            alert("Date should not be greater than Today's Date")
        }
    }
```

Any Help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Why the downvote? Am i not provided the sufficient data?

Comment: Instead of using a validating JavaScript function I would simply define the DateField's range.

Comment: @dennis could you update with an answer.it will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I'd encourager you not to use inline Javascript. Try to use UJS where possible i.e. instead of adding a onchange="blah". Try adding an event handler, in prototype I think this is done using [observe](http://prototypejs.org/doc/latest/dom/Event/observe/).

Secondly, Javascript doesn't have a `Date.today` call. so this will error. Try building it up, so start with just alerting if the onchange function has been fired. Then alert the value of the text box and the value of today (`new Date()`) Then the result of the equality check.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a validation try to define the range of the DateField, as the tag suggest you are using ruby on rails:

```
<%= form_for @new_object do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :date_attribute, id: 'date_select_me'%>
<% end %>

<script>
  $('#date_select_me').datepicker({
    minDate: '-1Y',
    maxDate: new Date(),
  });
</script>
```

This method uses jquery UI's DatePicker, at this configuration it will allow a user to select a Date between 1 year ago and Today.

source:
http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max